# When using memory BIOs with OpenSSL, how can you find the 'needed size' for the input BIO?

Tags: c++, openssl

Here's some sample code which shows how I'm using OpenSSL:

```
BIO *CreateMemoryBIO() {
    if (BIO *bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())) {
        BIO_set_mem_eof_return(bio, -1);    
        return bio;
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Could not create memory BIO");
}

m_readBIO = CreateMemoryBIO();
m_writeBIO = CreateMemoryBIO();
SSL_set_bio(m_ssl, m_readBIO, m_writeBIO);
```

Now, if I do an `SSL_Read`, and I get `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`, is there any way for me to find out how much it had tried to read internally (in other words, how much do I need to write with `BIO_write` to `m_readBIO` before `SSL_Read` would be satisfied?)

A good lower bound would work for me as well, my issue is that I need to report how much data to read to the layer above me, and it will not return control to me until it has read that much data (and I don't want to degenerate into 1-byte reads).

I'm aware that `SSL_Read` and `SSL_Write` may both alternately read & write due to handshaking and such, but I'm interested in the 'current' read that is being done internally.

If it's not possible to do with the standard `BIO_s_mem`, I assume it could be done if I wrote my own BIO which 'remembered' the size of the last read request which failed, so any pointers to documentation on writing custom BIOs (which, to my knowledge, is supported by OpenSSL) would also be appreciated.

Comment: How about [SSL_pending](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_pending.html)?

Comment: That function seems to be for the opposite problem, how much is available to read _from_ the SSL object (as opposed to how much is the SSL object trying to read)

Comment: Yes, my bad. Anyway it's not quite clear to me why you need the bytes number...If `SSL_read` (actually `SSL_get_error`) returned `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`, that mean that it wasn't able to read a complete record, so the bytes can't be decrypted, making them useless without the ones that will follow. However I browsed a little bit, and it probably might be possible by setting a callback (`BIO_set_callback`), that can access `BIO` 's underlying `BUF_MEM` structures.

Comment: If it returned `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`, then I want to know how many bytes I should write into the read BIO using `BIO_write`, _before_ I call `SSL_Read` again, I _don't_ want to read undecrypted data cached in the BIO.

Comment: Is it possible? Not sure what happens with the `SSL_read` 's `buf` argument in this case. Here's a quote from [SSL_read doc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_read.html): >"Only when a record has been completely received, it can be processed (decryption and check of integrity). Therefore data that was not retrieved at the last call of SSL_read() can still be buffered inside the SSL layer and will be retrieved on the next call to SSL_read()....Only when the record has been received and processed completely, SSL_read() will return reporting success."

Comment: Is this legal C++ syntax: `if (BIO *bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()))` ?

Comment: Yep. Equivalent to `{BIO *bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()); if (bio) ... }`

Comment: you can also use `BIO_pending(bio_obj)` after writing data to the BIO object .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to CristiFati for the suggesting BIO_set_callback, it seems to work. If you want to make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it, but I want to put the details here for posterity.

Inside my 'SSLSocket' class:

```
in the constructor:
BIO_set_callback(m_readBIO, &BIOCallback);
BIO_set_callback_arg(m_readBIO, reinterpret_cast<char*>(this));

long SSLSocket::BIOCallback(
    BIO *in_bio,
    int in_operation,
    const char* in_arg1,
    int in_arg2,
    long in_arg3,
    long in_returnValue)
{
    // in_bio isn't provided for BIO_CB_FREE.
    if (BIO_CB_FREE == in_operation)
    {
        return in_returnValue;
    }

    assert(in_arg1);

    return reinterpret_cast<SSLSocket*>(BIO_get_callback_arg(in_bio))->DoBIOCallback(
        in_bio,
        in_operation,
        in_arg1,
        in_arg2,
        in_arg3,
        in_returnValue);

long SSLSocket::DoBIOCallback(
    BIO *in_bio,
    int in_operation,
    const char* in_arg1,
    int in_arg2,
    long in_arg3,
    long in_returnValue)
{
    UNUSED(in_arg3);

    // We only care about the return callback for BIO_read()
    if ((BIO_CB_READ | BIO_CB_RETURN) == in_operation)
    {
        const int shouldRetry = BIO_should_retry(in_bio);
        const int bytesRequested = in_arg2;
        assert(bytesRequested > 0);

        if ((in_returnValue <= 0) && shouldRetry)
        {
            m_needBytes = bytesRequested;
        }
        else if ((in_returnValue > 0) && (in_returnValue < bytesRequested) && shouldRetry)
        {
            m_needBytes = bytesRequested - in_returnValue;
        }
        else
        {
            m_needBytes = 0;
        }
    }

    return in_returnValue;
}
```

Then I use `m_needBytes` to decide how much to write in BIO_write().